# The type name 'DatasetTableAdapters' does not exist in the type

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, tableadapter

I've added a `DataGridView` control to my `TabControl` to display data that is stored in a single table of a local application database called `Cellar.sdf`.

When I add the data source to the DataGridView, I select the table I want to display data from and preview the data. It displays the content inside the database.

When I build the project I get the following errors:

```
The type name 'CellarDataSetTableAdapters' does not exist in the type 'Winecellar.Winecellar'
The type name 'CellarDataSet' does not exist in the type 'Winecellar.Winecellar'
```

My project name is `'Winecellar'`. When I created the project in VS2012, it created a subfolder resulting in the file structure `'Winecellar.Winecellar'`, though I am not sure if this has something to do with this problem. Inside of the folder I indeed have the file `CellarDataSet` it says I am missing.

Do I have to create a separate `TableAdapter` for my database, or must I do things in a different order to get this to work?

The code lines that are causing my errors is in my Form1.Designer.cs file,

```
(1)        this.cellarDataSet = new Winecellar.CellarDataSet();
           this.wineBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
(2)        this.wineTableAdapter = new Winecellar.CellarDataSetTableAdapters.WineTableAdapter();
```

(I found a similar topic on the MSDN-forum, though I could not resolve my problem from reading it. [Read it here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cda4dc84-39dd-4a89-a8e5-754c9b583ea9/the-type-name-dataset-does-not-exist-in-the-type-ultratimeultratime)

Comment: I suppose your solution is called WineCellar as well? So you have a `...\WineCellar\WineCellar\WineCellar` folder?

Comment: In my projects folder it is structured as `...\Projects\Winecellar\Winecellar`

Comment: So which one is the solution folder?

Comment: The subfolder (the second one).

Comment: Please document you folder structure and namespaces carefully. It's the relevant part and we have to guess now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the code generator with the double namespace. Best thing to do is rename the subfolder and the associated namespace.

Short fix:

```
 //this.cellarDataSet = new Winecellar.CellarDataSet();
   this.cellarDataSet = new Winecellar.Winecellar.CellarDataSet();
```

Comment: This result in `The type name 'Winecellar' does not exist in the type 'Winecellar.Winecellar'`

Comment: Yes, my ability to guess your folders and namespaces is at an end here.

Comment: I modified the Project properties and renamed the namespace to a more unambiguous name and reasoning. Doing so the errors became more obvious to solve easily. In the future, I will name my application structure more carefully. Thank you!

Comment: Or you can just remove the namespace... `this.cellarDataSet = new CellarDataSet();` either way that solved the problem. Thank you!!!