# The type name does not exist in the type c# within InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, initializecomponent

I am really stuck on this error, the problem is whenever I try to add object `DataGrid` to my form  and link it to my SQL database then I am able to preview the data which is fine.  Upon compiling I am getting the above error `The type does not exit in the type` - when I double click on the error it takes me to the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Here is a sample of that code where the error is occurring :

```
this.wordsDataSet = new SpellingApplication.wordsDataSet();
this.wordListTableAdapter = new wordApplication.wordsDataSetTableAdapters.wordListTableAdapter();
```

so all I am doing at this stage is selecting a object `DataGrid` from toolbox placing this on the form and then linking this object to SQL via the small arrow , am able to preview the data , only get the error when compiling.

I have read Stack Overflow threads and am unable to correct the problem

Within my project properties my Application is set to .NET framework 4.5 and build application target is at x64 As per suggested by some of the treads on here.

Any help would be very much appreciated and if you can clarify your answer in simple terms / provide step by step instructions I would really appreciated as I am a newbie to C# / VS2015

Comment: Please show the exact and full compiler error.

Comment: please show the what error you exactly getting.

Comment: first you learn how ask good question follow this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: CodeCaster: the exact error in compiler is as follows : Error 1 The type name 'wordsDataSet' does not exist in the type 'SpellingApplication.SpellingApplication' C:\Users\Waheed\OneDrive\Project-TargetDev\UniversalAppSpelling\SpellingApplication\SpellingApplication\frmAmend.Designer.cs 34 57 SpellingApplication

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I have fix this error

Thanks to this tread [The type name 'DatasetTableAdapters' does not exist in the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044850/the-type-name-datasettableadapters-does-not-exist-in-the-type)

I renamded my namespace as my folder structure was correct  from :

this.wordDataSet = new SpellingApplication.wordDataSet(); to 
this.wordDataSet = new wordDataSet(); this fix

This also applies to the TableAdapter once again there is no stupid question to ask or a certain way of asking , please feel free to ask question on this tread as a newbie advancing in software engineering , I will always be glad to help.